# Linux Shared Library

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I am very new to linux Application Development.

I have two libraries shared libraries libGetData.so and libProcessData.so.

And I am Running two Different C++ Applications as A and B,on a Linux PC and using these two libraries in both applications.

I have few static variables in both libraries.

But, When I set a static variable in libGetData.so library from Application A. Its is not reflecting in Application B.

My goal is if I use a shared library in any Application and if I set any static variable in that library. Same thing should reflect on an-other application which is using same library.

Please help me...

Comment: Only the library code is shared, not the variable memory. Each process gets its own chunk of (virtualized) RAM to run the library code in.

Answer (score 5):

> But, When I set a static variable in libGetData.so library from Application A. Its is not reflecting in Application B.

Correct.

> My goal is if I use a shared library in any Application and if I set any static variable in that library. Same thing should reflect on an-other application which is using same library.

No, that's not how shared libraries work.

Shared libraries allow the *non-changing* parts of the library to be shared by multiple processes, but that's purely an implementation detail at the OS level. They do *not* mean the processes share an address space. Variables in different processes are distinct and not shared.

To have the processes communicate they need to use some form of [Inter-Process Communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) such as pipes, or sockets, or shared memory (which is unrelated to shared libraries).